# Calculating coordinates given a bearing and distance issues

Tags: c++, algorithm, coordinates, geography

I've been attempting to implement the function described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877524/calculating-coordinates-given-a-bearing-and-a-distance) in C++. It seems to work pretty well, but breaks down at large vales of `distance`, or when close to a pole. The angle at which the abrupt change in the first test case happens is around 243 degrees, which doesn't seem significant mathematically.

I'm using [hamstermap](http://www.hamstermap.com/quickmap.php) to map out the function output and [jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-compiler-c++/) to quickly compile/run the code - I can't zoom out enough to get good pictures, but to recreate the issue, here are a couple of test cases that demonstrate it (enter values in the function call in main() on line 35):

1: Set `distance` to 500,000, `startingLocation.lat` to -88 and `startingLocation.lon` to 173. Note that the distance value presents no problem at latitude values closer to the equator.

2: Set `distance` to 10,000,000, `startingLocation.lat` to -15 and `startingLocation.lon` to 173

What might be causing this issue?

```
// Value for pi
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846
// Mean radius of earth in m, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius#Average_distance_from_center_to_surface
#define REARTH 6371008.7714
// Threshold for equality in floating point operations
#define EPSILON 0.000001

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

struct LLlocation
{
    double lat;
    double lon;
};

void CalculatePosition(struct LLlocation *Location_0, struct LLlocation *Location_1, double, double, double=REARTH);
double deg2rad(double);
double rad2deg(double);

struct LLlocation startingLocation, finalLocation;

int main()
{
    startingLocation.lat = -88.000000000;
    startingLocation.lon = 173.000000000;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(9);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++)
    {
        CalculatePosition(&startingLocation, &finalLocation, 500000, i);
        //cout << "Leaving at " << i << " degrees\n";
        cout << finalLocation.lat << "," << finalLocation.lon << "\n";
    }
}

void CalculatePosition(struct LLlocation *Location_0, struct LLlocation *Location_1, double distance, double azimuth, double rearth)
{
    /*
    INPUTS
    Location_0.lat = starting latitude in decimal degrees
    Location_0.lon = starting longitude in decimal degrees
    distance = distance in meters
    azimuth = angle from North in decimal degrees
    */

    // Convert angles to radians and normalize distance
    double rlat1 = deg2rad(Location_0->lat);
    double rlon1 = deg2rad(Location_0->lon);
    double rbearing = deg2rad(azimuth);
    double rdistance = distance/rearth;

    // Use law of haversines to calculate new lat and lon
    double rlat2 = asin(sin(rlat1)*cos(rdistance)+cos(rlat1)*sin(rdistance)*cos(rbearing));

    double rlon2;
    if(cos(rlat2) == 0 || abs(cos(rlat2) < EPSILON))
    {
        //endpoint is a pole
        rlon2 = rlon1;
    } 
    else
    {
        rlon2 = (fmod((rlon1-asin(sin(rbearing)*sin(rdistance)/cos(rlat2))+PI),(2*PI)))-PI;
    }

    Location_1->lat = rad2deg(rlat2);
    Location_1->lon = rad2deg(rlon2);

}

double deg2rad(double d){
    return d*PI/180.0;
}

double rad2deg(double r){
    return r*180.0/PI;
}
```

Comment: Independent of any numerical issues (check for subtractive cancellation in intermediate computation), are you aware that use of the haversine formula means that a spherical earth is assumed, while the earth is not actually spherical? It is therefore best restricted to relatively short distances.

Comment: @njuffa yes I am, but I couldn't find any formulas that took into account the ellipsoidal nature of the earth. If you could direct me to a better one I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: My familiarity with ellipsoid-based computation is almost non-existent, but I think the following might be of help: Charles F. F. Karney, "Algorithms for geodesics." *J Geod* (2013) 87:43–55

Comment: This technically isn't an answer to the question, but I've accomplished my goal by using [Vincenty's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty's_formulae) instead